# Where Eclipse deploys servlets on GlassFish?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, eclipse-juno, glassfish-4, webaddress

I'm using `Eclipse Juno` with `GlassFish 4` on Widows 7 box. GlassFish is installed as local host.

If I keep all the defaults and deploy my Dynamic Web Project to the server via Eclipse, what will be the **Web address** for servlets?  What should I put into HTML form `action` parameter?

Servlet's class is annotated with `@WebServlet`.

Context root is `/WebProject`.

I do see the servlet deployed on the server, but getting ***404***s on all my attempts.

**UPDATE:**

It's working now. I simply haven't realized that `urlPatterns` value is **case-sensitive**.

Comment: In other words, you've just a `@WebServlet` without an URL like so `@WebServlet("/servletURL")`? Which book/tutorial did you use to learn servlets? Then I can contact its author about this severe misinstruction. If you however didn't use any and are just fiddling around, then I strongly recommend to not do that.

Comment: @ BalusC - No, I did specify `urlPatterns` parameter in addition to `description` and `name`.

Comment: Why don't you tell on which URL the servlet is been mapped then? Or did you not understand what that part meant? In other words, the book/tutorial you've at hands was doing a bad job in explaining how the stuff works?